# How to properly point domain.com/subfolder to a static website in Ruby with Rack?

Tags: ruby, static, config, rack

I've deployed a static website to Heroku using this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby

I've created this folder structure:

```
- site
  |- config.ru
  |- Gemfile
  |- public
     |- index.html
     |- images
     |- js
     |- css
     |- subfolder
        |- images
        |- js
        |- css
```

And wrote this to `config.ru`:

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"

use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public/subfolder"  

run lambda { |env|
  [
    200, 
    {
      'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' 
    },
    File.open('public/index.html', File::RDONLY)
  ]
}

map '/subfolder' do
  run Proc.new { |env|
    [
      200, 
      {
        'Content-Type'  => 'text/html', 
        'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=6400' 
      },
      File.open('public/subfolder/index.html', File::RDONLY)
    ]
  }
end
```

Now I want to have `domain.com` point to `public/index.html` and `domain.com/subfolder` point to `public/subfolder/index.html`. The landing pages seem to work properly, I just can't seem to serve their requests to the right directories (ie. correct `images`, `js` and `css` folders).

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: You may also find the [`Rack::Directory`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Directory) middleware useful, if you haven't seen it already

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are using routing in disagreement:

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public"
```

The above should for example serve `/js/jquery-min.js` from the `public` folder.

```
use Rack::Static, 
  :urls => ["/images", "/js", "/css"],
  :root => "public/subfolder"
```

Now if you try to use `public/subfolder` in the same way, `/js/jquery-min.js` should now be served from `public/subfolder/js/jquery-min.js`. Which is inconsistent.

Instead, try the following:

```
use Rack::Static, root: 'public',
  urls: %w( /images /js /css /subfolder )
```

And then route to assets with `/js/*` when you want the base directory, `/subfolder/js/*` when you need the subfolder one, or just `js/*` when you want to get the scripts for the same dir level of the html page.

Let me know if that fixes it!